# Why do I have poor video capture quality, and how can I improve it?

Tags: video, camera

I have a dual boot Lenovo Ideapad U260. If I use Skype or a Google+ hangout from Ubuntu, the video quality is a bit poor. I can't adjust the brightness either. But if I boot to Windows, the video quality is better.

Any suggestions for the applications that I can try to improve it?

Comment: For the brightness adjustment, try installing the [Video4Linux Control Panel](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/v4l2ucp).

Answer (score 4):

A good application that can be used to adjust webcam and video quality is [Video4Linux Control Centre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/v4l2ucp/)

This program allows you to change various parameters such as brightness, sharpness and contrast to hopefully improve the quality of your webcam/video capture device's picture quality.

To see the effects of any adjustments you are making you can use Skype. Enter the Skype options menu and select **Video Devices** and click the **Test** button. With this window open launch Video4Linux Control Centre and any changes you make to the settings can be seen to take effect in the preview window of Skype (You can double click the preview window to view this full screen). Or you could use a dedicated webcam application such as [Cheese](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cheese/) to view your video device's picture as you make changes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I install Intel ® Graphics for Linux and get the same video quality as Windows 7. I use the following link:

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0-linux

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.